# How to use OOP in this case?

Tags: php, laravel, oop

I have class that allows to export data from database.

There is method that takes parameter `$table`:

```
use App\User;

public function query($table){
   return User::get();
}
```

Problem is that I need to change `$table` in request. In this case I have default imported class `use App\User;` that allows me to use object-model `User`.

But if I want to use object dinamicly like as parameter?

So, I can do that:

```
if($table == "users"){
   return User::get();
} else if ($table == "clients") {
   return Client::get();
}
```

And import all model-classes in top class.

But this is not good way, I thing.

Comment: You could try something around http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php.

Comment: You can `return $table::get();`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you could try and create a map to map tables to objects.

```
$map = array('users' => User::class, 'clients' => Client::class);
$object = $map[$table];
return $object::get();
```

Comment: did you check it? It won't work for files in different namespace

Comment: Ofcourse it does, make sure to add the `use` statement to the top of your file.

Comment: Did you checked it? In one of my project it didn't work I have tested. But if you tested & worked then I have nothing to say.

Comment: Might be something wrong with your project setup then, but that is a different SO question.

Comment: I had to use full **`namespace`** `$map = array('users' => FULL_NAMESPACE_OF_USER::class, 'clients' => FULL_NAMESPACE_OF_CLIENT::class);` if they are in different namespace

Comment: May be is there any solution more OOP?